# Edit image and download using js

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have an image, which has to be presented to the user in my website. The user is supposed to encircle the part of the image that is already presented and then he should be able to download the image.

The download image as png or jpg must have my website image with the encircled marks.

The user must be presented with drawable pen or circle tool.

Which is the recommended method to achieve this ? Using html js.

Comment: You can do that using canvas.

Comment: I think you can use this library https://github.com/nhnent/tui.image-editor

Comment: @Dongju Jung thanks so much.